# Использование print в контексте выражения

Tags: print, php

> print всегда возвращает 1, поэтому может быть использован в контексте выражения

Что означает в контексте выражения? Пожалуйста, покажите на примере(-ах).

Comment: Источник укажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это значит, что `print` можно использовать внутри логического выражения, например:

```
if ((print "foo") && (print "bar")) {
    // безусловно попадаем сюда после вывода двух строк
}
```

Но так делать **не надо**, потому что вы сломаете мозг всем, кто будет читать ваш код. Считайте это наследием царского режима.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Использование в условиях
if (print 'bar') {
    // 'bar' was printed
}

// Функция вернет 1 (truthy)
function() {
    return print('hello');
}

// Присваивание значения ($a будет 1, а не True)
$a = print "True";
```

Answer (score 1):

Ораторы выше ответили достаточно ёмко, но добавлю:
Выражение - это условие в данном случае. Обычно `if(){}else{}`
Во времена когда динозавры кушали пещерных людей, а PHP переживал своё рождение, `print()` юзали в качестве проверки - смог ли оператор сбросить в STDOUT переданное?
Сейчас же это конструкция языка, которая только номинально числится функцией, а главная особенность функций - это обязательное возвращение чего-либо. [Поэтому пока что возвращает число 1. Всегда.](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print.php)
Думаю в будущем уберут эту особенность, хотя может и нет - зачем трогать то, что и так работает хорошо?